# Caching and Parsing etag with HttpClient and Odatav4(Etag always null in Httpclient)

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, odata

**The case** : I'm Using EF6 and WebApi controls to store my result

```
    public class Profile
{
    public string ZipFile { get; set; } // input parameter
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // output parameter generated by Web API

    public string Name { get; set; } // output parameter from Profile XML file

    public string Description { get; set; } // output parameter from Profile XML file}
```

So i'm using ConcurrencyCheck to generate etag with odataV4

When i'm reading the get result with post man i getting :
[image]

As you see the etage there

**The problem** : in my client i use HttpClient as follows

```
 public static string GetAsJsonAsync(string route)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        try
        {

            var fullRoute = PrepareHttpRequest(route);
            var client = new HttpClient();
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(fullRoute).Result)
            {
                result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException(result, ex);
        }

        return result;


    }
```

the response header if-match and etag are always ,I have no idea how to parse the "@odata.etg" value, 
so my question is how i parsing the etag value and store it?

Answer (score 0):

For future references the solution is Attach to your model     `[JsonProperty("@odata.etag")]`